# How to quickly initialize ruby project development environment?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

How to specify gem dependencies in a way that user with only ruby, rake and rubygems installed could issue a single rake command to install all the dependencies required? Is it possible to use the same dependency specification when building gem with GemBuildTask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy to set up a rake task that installs a bunch of gems:

```
task :install_gems do
  require "rubygems"
  require "rubygems/dependency_installer"

  installer = Gem::DependencyInstaller.new

  [["rack"], ["merb-core", "1.0.12"]].each do |args|
    installer.install(*args)
  end
end
```

Of course, you could extract this into a method and write a prettier way to specify your dependencies, but this should work great.

Comment: I like this - it's a good way to offer to install dependencies for end users as well.

Comment: Of course, we're working on a solution that will be much more robust in Rails 3 that will be available for standalone apps as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I think currently you'd have to write a custom rake task that talked to the Gem library.

It's possible that [rip](http://hellorip.com/about.html), the (very) new kid on the block, will make it all easier, but it's very early days.

But someone else may have a better way...

Answer (score 0):

If your app is packaged as a gem, you could add the dependencies to the gemspec and rubygems will attempt to install them for you when you install the gem.

There are a bunch of ways to make a gem out of some ruby code. Recently I have taken to using [jeweler](http://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler/tree/master).

With it, you can install a project as a gem by running `rake install`. There are some instructions on how to do dependencies on its github wiki.